# Convert byte[] to char[]

Tags: c#, arrays, character-encoding, type-conversion

How do I convert a `byte` array to a `char` array in C#?

Comment: You first need to determine the encoding (if you don't know it). [W3C's spec for HTML5 §8.2.2.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#determining-the-character-encoding) provides steps for determining the encoding for an HTML5 page, but it contains some steps that could be adopted for other applications.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

```
System.Text.Encoding.ChooseYourEncoding.GetString(bytes).ToCharArray();
```

Substitute the right encoding above: e.g.

```
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes).ToCharArray();
```

Answer (score 21):

You must know the source encoding.

```
string someText = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(someText);
char[] chars = Encoding.Unicode.GetChars(bytes);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
byte[] a = new byte[50];

char [] cArray= System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(a).ToCharArray();
```

From the URL thedixon posted

http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/250261-byte-char

You cannot ToCharArray the byte without converting it to a string first.

To quote Jon Skeet there

> There's no need for the copying here -
>   just use Encoding.GetChars. However,
>   there's no guarantee that ASCII is
>   going to be the appropriate encoding
>   to use.