# How to Declare byte* ( byte array ) in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays

How to Declare byte* ( byte array ) in c++  and how to define as a parameter in function  definition?

when I declare like below

Function Declaration:

```
int Analysis(byte* InputImage,int nHeight,int nWidth);
```

Getting error : "byte" undefined

Comment: use unsigned char instead. its the same....one byte

Comment: then how should i convert byte* in to unsigned char, getting byte array input from the C# application.

Comment: Did you want to convert byte from c# to char in c++? am i understand this correctly?

Comment: I think you can do this by convert byte into char in c# before pass on to c++ char

Comment: This one should help you in converting byte in c# to char http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431004/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-char-in-c-sharp

Comment: but i don't think the explicit conversion will be necessary. May be it is already compatible. try it out and let us know :)

Comment: `byte*` is **not** a byte array. It's a **pointer** _to_ a `byte`; commonly the first element, but it doesn't have to be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no type `byte` in C++. You should use `typedef` before. Something like

```
typedef std::uint8_t byte;
```

in C++11, or

```
typedef unsigned char byte;
```

in C++03.

Answer (score 5):

The C++ type representing a byte is `unsigned char` (or other sign flavour of `char`, but if you want it as plain bytes, `unsigned` is probably what you're after).

However, in modern C++, you shouldn't be using raw arrays. Use `std::vector<unsigned char>` if your array is runtime-size, or `std::array<unsigned char, N>` (C++11) if your array is of static size `N`. You can pass these to functions via (const) references, like this:

```
int Analysis(std::vector<unsigned char> &InputImage, int nHeight, int nWidth);
```

If `Analysis` does not modify the array or its elements, do this instead:

```
int Analysis(const std::vector<unsigned char> &InputImage, int nHeight, int nWidth);
```